# Using Chrome Developer Tab for realtime html and javascript testing

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

In Google chrome web browser

about:blank gives an empty page and F12 gives you access to Developer Tab.

Right-clicking a source in **Elements** gives **Edit as Html** Option in Developer Tab

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>


    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <button id="myBtn">Button</button>
    </div>

    <div id="demo">

    </div>

    <script>
    document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function () {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
    });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Above is a  JavaScript snippet which I copied in. But JavaScript code is not executing.  Is this work flow of real time html editing not supported in chrome ?

Answer (score 1):

Your script would ran, if it existed there when the page gets loaded. After the page has loaded, no script tags will just run when edited in.

You could wrap everything inside the script tags into a function and call that I think, however.

One other, but kind of a useless and technical trick that might let you run JavaScript, by editing in elements after the page has loaded, looks something like this:

If you add that in to the loaded page's HTML, the script inside that input-element's onfocus-attribute should run. This, however, is no proper way to do anything other than Cross-Site Scripting (XSS).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `template literal`, `document.write()` at `console`. At `about:blank` page press `F12`, at `console` enter

```
var html = `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <button id="myBtn">Button</button>
    </div>
    <div id="demo">
    </div>
    <script>
    document.getElementById("myBtn").addEventListener("click", function () {
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
    });
    </script>   
</body>
</html>`;

document.write(html);
```

then click `<button>` element.

---

You can alternatively click `Sources` -> `Snippets`, type or paste the above `javascript` at center window, click right-pointing triangle at right panel to run `javascript` at `Snippets`. You can also right-click at `Snippets` panel to create a new snippet to run.